# Are the names of parked domain websites trademarked?

Tags: trademark

If somebody registered a distinctive website name, that has no content or services related to it (i.e. it's an empty page), is the name trademarked?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_parking

Answer (score 1):

To create a trade mark, the name must be **used** in trade, so no.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by in trade?

Comment: trade Noun 1.the action of buying and selling goods and services